Chained ModelSelect2Widget
I have these models:
from django.db import models

class ValidationCheckType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    nicename = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nicename


class ValidationCheckTarget(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    nicename = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = models.ForeignKey('ValidationCheckType', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return ' - '.join([self.type.nicename, self.nicename])


class DirectiveCheck(models.Model):
    directive = models.ForeignKey(Directive, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    check_type = models.ForeignKey(ValidationCheckType, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='types')
    check_target = models.ForeignKey(ValidationCheckTarget, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='targets')
    target_value = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

So, ValidationCheckType represents the top-level category, filtering ValidationCheckTarget choices to ensure only relevant targets are displayed based on the selected type. Or so it should be.
Now to the forms. According to django_select2.forms.ModelSelect2Widget and customizing-a-form I should be able to do something like this:
from django import forms
from django_select2 import forms as s2forms
from .models import DirectiveCheck, ValidationCheckTarget, ValidationCheckType

class DirectiveCheckForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DirectiveCheck
        fields = ['check_type', 'check_target', 'target_value']
        widgets = {
            'check_type': s2forms.ModelSelect2Widget(
                model=ValidationCheckType,
                search_fields=['nicename__icontains'],
            ),
            'check_target': s2forms.ModelSelect2Widget(
                model=ValidationCheckTarget,
                search_fields=['nicename__icontains'],
                dependent_fields={'check_type': 'id'},  
                max_results=10,
                attrs={
                    "data-minimum-input-length": 0,
                    "data-placeholder": "Select a check_type first",
                }
            )
        }

The good news is, the check_type dropdown works.
The bad news is, the check_target dropdown does not. It does not filter the results according to the selection in check_type.
If I access the auto-generated AJAX URL created by the widget and use it for testing, I (seem to) only get results when I use query parameters that don't appear as fields in the model. Obviously I'm missing some crucial point in the workflow. But what?
I also found this link about django_select2, but the question there specifically revolves around the admin side of things. Me, on the other hand, need the front end.
